# ng-click not firing in area rendered after initial page load

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have inherited a site that uses Angular.js and it has some functionality for tracking Google Analytics. For some reason any ng-click items are not firing if they are created after the initial view is loaded. How the page works:

1. Page is loaded with a search box
2. After search is executed a list of results is displayed and several of the A tags have ng-click in them.

As stated, the ng-click doesn't fire. Here is the relevant portion of the code:

```
angular.module("backinfocus").controller("DoctorDetail", ["$scope", "$http", "$window", "$q",
    function(n, t, i, r) {
        function u(n, t) {
            t = t || r.defer();
            var i = f(n);
            return e.geocode({
                address: i
            }, function(i, r) {
                if (r == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    var f = i[0].geometry.location;
                    t.resolve({
                        address: n,
                        location: f
                    })
                } else r == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT ? setTimeout(function() {
                    u(n, t)
                }, 1e3) : t.reject(r)
            }), t.promise
        }
        n.trackWebsite = function() {
            var t = n.result,
                i = n.selectedAddress;
            trackEvent("Doc Finder", "Details Page-Click View Website Button", t.doctorId + ", " + t.name + ", " + i.website)
        };
        n.trackDirections = function() {
            var i = n.result,
                t = n.selectedAddress;
            trackEvent("Doc Finder", "Details Page-Click Driving Directions Button", i.doctorId + ", " + i.name + ", " + t.name + " " + t.address1 + " " + t.address2 + ", " + t.city + ", " + t.state + " " + t.zipCode)
        };

    }
]);
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                                <div class="result_contact">
                                    <span ng-if="result.TollPhone">Toll-free: {{result.TollPhone}}<br></span>
                                    <span ng-if="result.LocalPhone">Phone: {{result.LocalPhone}}<br></span>
                                    <a ng-if="result.Website" href="" ng-href="{{result.Website}}" target="_blank" title="{{result.Website}}" ng-click="trackWebsite(result);">View Website</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Any idea why this doesn't fire? Does it matter that the Javascript functions have no parameter yet the code passes a parameter? Could that be the problem?

Incidentally, the console shows this error that I can't seem to understand:

ReferenceError: address is not defined
    at h.n.trackWebsite (app.js:300)
    at Za.functionCall (angular.js:10348)
    at angular.js:18333
    at h.$get.h.$eval (angular.js:12175)
    at h.$get.h.$apply (angular.js:12273)
    at HTMLAnchorElement. (angular.js:18332)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.v.event.dispatch (jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.v.event.add.o.handle.u (jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:9563$get @ angular.js:7004$get.h.$apply @ angular.js:12275(anonymous function) @ angular.js:18332v.event.dispatch @ jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2v.event.add.o.handle.u @ jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2

Any ideas?

Comment: The error says `address is not defined` and in your element you have `address1` and `address2`, I'm thinking that has something to do with it (one should probably be named `address`).

Comment: Is Angular involved in the insertion of the search results?  If not, that's the problem.  It has to see the ng-click when the search results are loaded to hook up the event-handler.

Comment: Figured it out. The previous developer made some object reference errors along with property naming errors.